# Is it possible to test an email popup window in cypress?

Tags: cypress

For my job I am required to test a form which, on submitting, opens the users default mail system and auto populates that email with the details entered into the form as shown below: [image: Form and email popup]

I want to know if it is possible for me to validate the email content using cypress to check that it matches that entered within the form. Or if not then whether or not I can verify that a popup has at least created. I think this may not be possible though as I think the window is separate from the browser, if so please confirm.

I'm all ears to any ideas!

Comment: Unfortunately, Cypress will never be able to test that second window/tab - https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs#Multiple-tabs . Is there a function that runs when you hit submit, and if so can you post it? You may be able to assert on the function being called (with certain data?)

Comment: You can probably set up a task to check the process name is alive and running after sending the click.

Answer (score 0):

1.While Submitting the form . You can Check email field as valid or not.
2.When you submit your form check which method you use .
if you use Post method just check the email files with this code -
This is javascript code to check whether email is valid or not.

```
email.match(
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9] 
{1,3}\. 
[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
);
```

3. You can also check email just HTML attribute use input type = "email" for example

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't think this answers the question - The email isn't submitted when I hit submit, I get the popup email window on my systems default mailer so there is no post request sent. I want to verify the content on the popup window ideally or at least verify one has opened.